# How can i search in xsl with jquery

Tags: jquery, xslt

I want to search data from xml through xsl.

I've created an xsl stylesheet and I'm showing it with jquery, now I want when the people input the keyword or select combobox macth with value of xml the xsl will show the true value
example

One
Two

and when people input One or select on combobox One  and click button Find the XSL will show result is One.

Comment: Share the code, dude. :)

Answer (score 0):

Your question isn't entirely clear to me, but maybe you could use XPath? jQuery has XPath selector support. This article may help:

[jQuery Tip: Using XPath Selectors](http://dev-tips.com/featured/jquery-tip-using-xpath-selectors)